# Azure DevOps Service Connections not showing when setting up a new release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, serviceconnection

I have setup a Service Connections within Azure DevOps to my Azure Subscription. It uses a certificate to connect. When I create a new pipeline and select the task `Azure App Service Deploy`.

In the drop down box for Azure Subscription I see nothing under Available Azure Service Connections, but I see my various Azure Subs under Available Azure Subscriptions.

Anyone Know what this could be? Is there some permission I am missing?

I have been looking about online and cannot really see anything.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to run your agent on a different type of virtual machine, please see Picture 1 below.

Try selecting a different OS and add a new task based on your selected vm. Also note that your service connection may not be available for the selected task as you can see in Picture 2 and Picture 3.

*Assuming you have already enabled pipeline permissions from the project settings in your repo.

Hope it helps.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about below in the UI, select the connection name you assigned in the Azure subscription (or the equivalent connection name) setting of your pipeline.

[image]

Next you must authorize the service connection. To do this, use one of the following techniques:

- If you want to authorize any pipeline to use the service connection,
  go to Azure Pipelines, open the Settings page, select Service
  connections, and enable the setting **Allow all pipelines to use this
  connection** option for the connection.
- If you want to authorize a service connection for a specific
  pipeline, open the pipeline by selecting **Edit** and queue a build
  manually. You will see a resource authorization error and a
  "Authorize resources" action on the error. Choose this action to
  explicitly add the pipeline as an authorized user of the service
  connection.

Comment: The Service Connection I created is not showing in that location. That is what I was saying in my question. Cheers

Comment: @markblue777 Did this only occurs on your specific release pipeline or all pipelines such as build pipeline. Have you try to enable the setting **Allow all pipelines to use this connection** option for the connection and try again.

Comment: On all pipelines I am getting this error. It is enabled for all pipelines. The service connection type i made was Azure Classic. I am thinking this might be the wrong type for the deploy type being used. Just confirming this theory

Comment: I'm also using Azure Classic and it doesn't show up. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with the Service connection not showing up.

We had 2 projects configured in Azure Devops and each project had a service connection defined with the same name. 
It turned out that Azure Devops couldn't handle the duplicate name. We renamed one and everything was fine again

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue, and it turns out you can't use service connections that are scoped to the `Management Group` level in the classic release pipeline. It seems to work fine in a YAML pipeline though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Azure Devops does not list your Azure suscription this is the way to get the verify working for the service connection and get a deployment ok:

[image: The desired result]

Do the steps described in this link:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-azure-resource-manager-manual-service-%C3%A7i%C4%9Fdem-kadako%C4%9Flu

After that you can deploy sucessfully using that service connection.